# PayPal adaptive payment flow on React Native

Tags: react-native, paypal, webview, braintree, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm creating an app with react native that have a payment module with credit card and PayPal as payment module. The payment is automatically transferred to a vendor account subscribed in our platform
(**Buyer -> Platform -> Vendor**).

I already successfully created this payment flow in the credit card payment module using stripe as a payment gateway but i didn't find a way to do it with PayPal.

[image]

Here's a list of what i tried:

1. **Adaptive payment**: the problem with PayPal adaptive payment is that's it's not mobile friendly, the [standard checkout page](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-XXX) is not even close to being responsive. The lightbox checkout page need to open a new Popup which is not possible with RN WebView. And the Mini-Browser one do not return a response after the payment is done (check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28113162/6450941))
2. **Braintree SDK**: Braintree has a pretty great SDK for RN that i already tested and it works great, the problem is that i need to use Braintree's master-merchant and sub-merchants technique to achieve the payment flow i need, but [this technique is only available in the US and the funds needs to be in USD](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/overview#compatibility) and my application is deployed in France using EUR as a currency.
3. **Braintree SDK with PayPal payout**: I could create a Braintree account to receive all the funds and then send each one to it's receiver (vendor) automatically but i couldn't find a way to do this

If anyone have an idea of how could i create this flow with PayPal on RN.

Comment: What react native braintree sdk are you using? and how did you implement braintree marketplace?

Comment: This is one the most well written SO posts I've ever seen. bravo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed with using the PayPal express checkout with a payee object.
If you want to know more about this functionality i advice you to read more about it here: https://www.paypal-engineering.com/2017/01/03/setting-payee/ .

Now instead of calling the Adaptive Payment API i use the regular payment API with a custom payee and then give the user the express checkout link generated dynamically and finally i call the execute payment API to make the payment after having the client authorization.